# Is there anyway to make an object managed by Best_In_place also be a link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, best-in-place

I am using the [Best In Place gem](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place).

This is an example of my object:

```
<h5><%= best_in_place node, :name, as: :input, activator: "#edit-node-title-#{node.id}" %> <%= link_to "<i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>".html_safe, "#", id: "edit-node-title-#{node.id}" %></h5>
```

But what I want to do is have the `node.name` attribute be shown as a regular link.

So just `link_to node.name, node`.

How do I combine the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `display_with` option? It takes a helper or proc. I would prefer a helper, but for brevity I show it with a proc:

```
<%= best_in_place node, :name, as: :input, 
                               activator: "#edit-node-title-#{node.id}" 
                               display_with: proc{|node| link_to node.name, node_path(node) }
%> 
<%= link_to "<i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>".html_safe, "#", id: "edit-node-title-#{node.id}" %>
```

Comment: So the helper version would simply include the name of the helper method in the `display_with: ` option? So for instance, say the helper method is: `link_to_node(node)`, I would include just the `link_to` in the method, and then just include the name of the method in the `display_with`?

Comment: Indeed. You can check the [documentation](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place#using-display_with) for some examples.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your `Best in Place` tag inside of a `link_to` tag:

```
<h5>
  <%= link_to node_path(node) do %><!-- Or whatever path you want to link_to --> 
    <%= best_in_place node, :name, as: :input, activator: "#edit-node-title-#{node.id}" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to "#", id: "edit-node-title-#{node.id}" do %>
    <i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>
  <% end %>
</h5>
```

I also edited your activator link so it is a block too. This is untested, but it should work.